# Grant user Permission using Wild Card on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to Grant for example an insert permission for spacific user in all databases started by WA_ for example in my server

I make the following syntax but it dosent work

GRANT SELECT ON `wa_\_%`.`compoundshapeitems` TO `fofo`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY '123456' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have two underscores in the database name if you want to give access to databases called `wa_*`?

Have you tried something like the following:

```
grant select on `wa_%`.table to user@localhost identified by 'pass';
```

Disclaimer: I've not actually checked if wildcards are valid for the database in MySQL privileges.

Comment: yes i try it but it dosen't work.

Comment: it dosent work and  gives me this error
Table 'wa_%.mytable' doesn't exist